# ViewState is not working in class in app_code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please help with this. Is Viewstate allow to use in class in app_code?

I have this code in app_code but it seems not working. the viewstate always set to nothing.How can I keep a value in ViewState within a class in my App_Code folder?

```
 Public Property GridViewSortDirection() As String

            Get
                Return IIf(ViewState("SortDirection") = Nothing, "ASC", ViewState("SortDirection"))
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                ViewState("SortDirection") = value
            End Set
 End Property
```

This the code that set the value of the GridviewSortDirectio

```
Public Function GetSortDirection() As String

            Select Case GridViewSortDirection
                Case "ASC"
                    GridViewSortDirection = "DESC"
                Case "DESC"
                    GridViewSortDirection = "ASC"
            End Select

            Return GridViewSortDirection
        End Function
```

Then the getSortDirection is called in page (test.aspx.vb)

Comment: show how you are setting and getting the value - in which methods are you doing that etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you view source in your browser you will see a lot of gibberish, just search for VIEWSTATE and you will see it. This is important because HTTP requests are stateless, meaning that every request to the server the browser leaves the old page and takes the new page.

During a postback this is a problem because you are essentially leaving the page and getting a clean new one back, it just happens to be the same page. There needs to be a way to save the **state** of the page such as dropdown selections or textbox input, and this is done through the ViewState. The gibberish you see is this information as encoded data used to maintain the state.

When you refresh the browser window (the button at the top) the ViewState is lost and the data reverts to it's original state.

App_Code are classes stored on the **server** nothing to do with the **page**. This is why there is no ViewState in App_Code. If you want to maintain state outside of the page, then `Session` stores data on the server until you close the browser window. In your case it is probably more appropriate to just pass the data as a parameter

```
Public Function GetSortDirection(direction) As String
            Select Case direction
                Case "ASC"
                    Return "DESC"
                Case "DESC"
                    Return "ASC"
            End Select
        End Function
```

For an in-depth explanation read MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Comment: can you explain this mored deeply.. i'm quite lost. i will not use the public property?

Comment: I confirm that viewstate is not working in app_code, maybe my implementation is not correct. I tried to run the code in aspx.vb and viewstate is working.

Comment: So I will not use the public property anymore. I'm quite lost on how to pass data as parameter. How will pass the getsortdirection in my viewstate.. sorry

Comment: i recommend investing in a book such as http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-ASP-NET-4-in-C-and-VB.productCd-0470502215.html. Good luck!